# Replace Nan by a number in a cell array with Matlab

Tags: matlab, replace, nan

```
a = { [5 5 5 6 ] [ Nan Nan Nan Nan]; [ 7 8 8 8 ] [1 2 3 5] }
```

i want to replace `a{1,2}` by `[1 1 1 1 ]`

Is it possible? because I tried this function:

```
function k = non(a)
[l ,c ] = size(a);

for i= 1 : l

  for j =1 : c
     if a{i,j} == [ NaN NaN NaN NaN ]
          k{i,j} = [ 1 1 1 1] 
     else
          k{i,j} = a{i,j} ;
     end
  end
end
end
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: you should use `isequal(a{i,j}, [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN])` instead of `a{i,j} == [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]`. There are other ways to improve this code, but you should try this first.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar: No, you cannot do this with `NaN`s!!  A `NaN` value is never equal to anything, not even itself!  Try `isequal(NaN, NaN)` and you will see it is False (0)!  You are possibly thinking of `isnan()`.

Comment: @gariepy I know... I don't understand what I was thinking when I wrote this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the following simple function:

```
function matrix = replace_nan(matrix, value)
  matrix(isnan(matrix)) = value;
end
```

and then use cellfun to execute it over all elements of your cell array (I have generalized your problem slightly by allowing you to define `value` as the number to replace the NaN with, and making the elements variable length):

```
>> a = {[ 3 NaN] [NaN NaN NaN] [1 2 3 4 5 NaN 0 NaN]};
>> value = 1; %% the value to replace the NaN with
>> z = cellfun(@replace_nan, a, repmat( {value}, size(a,1), size(a,2)) , 'UniformOutput', 0);
>> z{1}
ans =
     3     1
>> z{2}
ans =
     1     1     1
>> z{3}
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     1     0     1
```

A few comments on the use of `cellfun` here: `cellfun` takes a function, in this case `replace_nan`, and a cell array, in this case `a`, and iterates the function call to `replace_nan()`.  If `replace_nan` were a single argument function, we could say `cellfun(@replace_nan, a)`, but the way I defined it, the function takes two arguments.  The way to specify that in cellfun is to provide a second cell array with the `value` arguments.  That is the `repmat({1},size(a,1),size(a,2))` which creates a second cell array with the same dimensions as `a`, but filled with `1`'s.

EDIT: The comment discussion brings up a good point: you cannot use `==` to test for `NaN`, you must use MATLAB's `isnan()` function.

```
>> [NaN NaN] == [NaN NaN]
ans =
     0     0
>> isnan( [NaN NaN] )
ans =
     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even shorter this way:

```
a(cellfun(@(cell) any(isnan(cell(:))),a))={[1 1 1 1]};
```